# Json Deserializer in C# is returning Incorrect Values from Json Request Response

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am attempting to return the Json response deserialized from the following https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json

Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using RestSharp;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Globalization;

namespace SupremeMobileMonitor
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var program = new Program();
            await program.GetItem();

        }
        // Declaring variables in the list
        static List<ItemDetail> ProductList = new List<ItemDetail>();
        List<string> productDesc = new List<string> { "new_item", "price", "category", "imageurl", "itemURL" };
        List<string> category = new List<string> { "jackets", "shirts", "tops_sweaters", "pants", "hats", "accessories", "shoes", "skate" };

        //creating a class for intializing Json Deserializer 

        public class MobileStockResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("unique_image_url_prefixes")]
        public List<object> UniqueImageUrlPrefixes { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("products_and_categories")]
        public Dictionary<string, List<ProductsAndCategory>> ProductsAndCategories { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("release_date")]
        public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("release_week")]
        public string ReleaseWeek { get; set; }
    }
        public partial class ProductsAndCategory
        {
            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public long Id { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("image_url")]
            public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("image_url_hi")]
            public string ImageUrlHi { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("price")]
            public long Price { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("sale_price")]
            public long SalePrice { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("new_item")]
            public bool NewItem { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("position")]
            public long Position { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("category_name")]
            public string CategoryName { get; set; }


        }


        //Initializing HttpClient for Requests and po
        public async Task GetItem()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json"),
                Method = HttpMethod.Get
            };
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductsAndCategory>(responseContent);

            Console.WriteLine(responseObject);




        }



    }
}
```

When I try to return a value (example: responseObject.id) It will just return '0'

When I try to return the complete response, it returns "SupremeMobileMonitor.Program+ProductsAndCategory"

Any idea why I can't get it returned and what I'm messing up my deserialization? Unfortunately the category known as "new" on the endpoint interferes with the C# keywords therefore removing my option to use dynamic deserialization.

Comment: Yes, the class is created based on the json that I have pulled from the API.

Comment: Or you could just serialize the object you just deserialized. That would work too :-D .... Jawad beat me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jslowik has the correct answer for your question, how to deserialize it.

To Print the object, you can either create an override `ToString()` method and print out only the things you are interested in, or you can print the object by serializing it to a string.

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(productsAndCategories, Formatting.Indented);
```

This will give you a json representation again of the object and show you all the values.

SideNote: If you want to get specific items from, Say, Bags, you can use Linq to get it...

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseObject.ProductsAndCategories["Bags"].Select(x => x.Id)));

// Output:
[173389,172978,173019,172974,173018,173001]
```

Answer (score 1):

Off hand I would just deserialize the full object. Example:

```
// Full model represented by your class
var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MobileStockResponse>(responseContent);

// The products and categories dictionaries you're looking for
var productsAndCategories = responseObject.ProductsAndCategories;
```

Comment: When using ```Console.WriteLine(prodcutsAndCategories);```     It returns the following: ```System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SupremeMobileMonitor.Program+ProductsAndCategory]]```

Comment: You can't really view objects like that. Set a break point and use the debugger and you should see what you're looking for. Also, you don't need to set the products and categories as a discrete variable. Just did it for illustartion purposes.